# cannot find symbol stripe.createPaymentMethod

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I stuck at this point and getting the next error in Android Studio when I try to run the app.

Can not find symbol stripe.createPaymentMethod()

[image]

So, I wanted to integrate this https://github.com/baranyildirim/google_pay/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/googlepay/googlepay/GooglePayPlugin.java in my APP.

But came to light this part is mostly deprecated and not working

```
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
    PaymentData paymentData = PaymentData.getFromIntent(data);
    CardInfo info = paymentData.getCardInfo();
    UserAddress address = paymentData.getShippingAddress();
    String rawToken = paymentData.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken();
    Token stripeToken = Token.fromString(rawToken);
    Map<String, Object> arguments = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    arguments.put("token", stripeToken.getId());

    if (stripeToken != null) {
        channel.invokeMethod("onGooglePaySuccess", arguments);
    }
    else {
        channel.invokeMethod("onGooglePayFailed", null);
    }
```

break;

Then I decided to replace this to the next

```
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
final PaymentData paymentData = PaymentData.getFromIntent(data);
if (paymentData == null) {
    channel.invokeMethod("onGooglePayFailed", null);
} else {
    final PaymentMethodCreateParams paymentMethodCreateParams =
        PaymentMethodCreateParams.createFromGooglePay(
            new JSONObject(paymentData.toJson()));

    stripe.createPaymentMethod(
        paymentMethodCreateParams,
        new ApiResultCallback<PaymentMethod>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentMethod result) {
                channel.invokeMethod("onGooglePaySuccess", result.id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                channel.invokeMethod("onGooglePayFailed", null);
            }
        }
    );
}
break;
```

And of course I imported some other stuff, like:

```
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;    
import com.stripe.android.ApiResultCallback;    
import com.stripe.android.GooglePayJsonFactory;    
import com.stripe.android.model.PaymentMethod;    
import com.stripe.android.model.PaymentMethodCreateParams;    
import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration;    
import com.stripe.android.PaymentIntentResult;    
import com.stripe.android.model.PaymentIntent;    
import com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget;    
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
```

And then I got the error, mentioned above. AndroidManifest.xml, dependencies ... etc. set as needed.

Comment: Can you include the code where you initialize Stripe (https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/stripe/com.stripe.android/-stripe/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the post. So I'm totally new in this Java package integrate in to Android Studio thing (this is the first time), even more I do not have too much experience with flutter/dart and nothing with JAVA. I want to integrate the Google Pay over Stripe in Android and I found this GitHub package, which close to that what I want to achieve. When first I integrated this package as written in its installation guide, I could make it work, the only problem was that, I could not pass different currency, that's why I started to make these changes.

Comment: Sorry should've been clearer - I'm still not seeing where you're declaring the stripe variable - something like `private Stripe stripe;`. This sample has an example (https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/without-webhooks/client/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/CheckoutActivityJava.java#L53) which doesn't use Google Pay but does call stripe.createPaymentMethod()

Comment: Karbi ... you were absolutely right! I was blind. After that still got some errors, but finally I could make a run. Thanks so much!!!! You did not give an answer so I can't accept it for points ... or I don't know how that exactly work here on stack overflow ... but I'm gonna close the flow if you don't mind.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)